# SOAP request element name not the same as in WSDL

Tags: xml, soap, wsdl

I imported the WSDL from a 3rd party, and generated the Java classes, using IntelliJ. When I send the SOAP request, the names in my XML does not correspond to the names defined in the WSDL.

Using a tool, such as SoapUI, the XML imports fine and the element names are as expected.

It looks like the marshalling is ignoring the @XmlElementRef annotation and uses the variable type.

This is what I expect:

```
               <rxh2:Documents>
                  <rxh2:Document>
                     <rxh2:Base64String>JVBERi0xLjQN</rxh2:Base64String>
                     <rxh2:DocumentType>Pdf</rxh2:DocumentType>
                  </rxh2:Document>
               </rxh2:Documents>
```

However, my XML comes out like this - **why is it called ArrayOfDocument instead of Documents?**

```
        <ns2:ArrayOfDocument>
            <ns2:Document>
                <ns2:Base64String>JVBERi0xLjYKJbiakp0KMS</ns2:Base64String>
                <ns2:DocumentType>Pdf</ns2:DocumentType>
            </ns2:Document>
        </ns2:ArrayOfDocument>
```

The setup for importing the WSDL in my pom.xml is defined like this:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <wsdlUrls>
            <wsdlUrl>
              https://thewebsite/Integration/Service.OrderService.svc?wsdl
            </wsdlUrl>
          </wsdlUrls>
          <extension>true</extension>
          <verbose>true</verbose>
          <vmArgs>
            <vmArg>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</vmArg>
          </vmArgs>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>endpoint.hpc</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>wsimport</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <packageName>com.cgm.ms.script</packageName>
              <args>
                <arg>-B-XautoNameResolution</arg>
              </args>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

Looking at the generated code, I see this:

```
    @XmlElementRef(name = "Documents", namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2010/12/Service.Models.RFM", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    protected JAXBElement<ArrayOfDocument> documents;
```

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ArrayOfDocument", propOrder = {
    "document"
})
public class ArrayOfDocument {

    @XmlElement(name = "Document", nillable = true)
    protected List<Document> document;
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end, all we needed to do was to change the ObjectFactory.java file. We changed the localPart from ArrayOfDocument to Documents and now our xml is 100%.

```
 private static final QName _ArrayOfDocument_QNAME = new QName("http://schemas.datacontract.org/2010/12/Service.Models.RFM", "Documents");
```

Result:

```
        <ns2:Documents>
            <ns2:Document>
                <ns2:Base64String>JVBERi0xLjYKJbiakp0KMSAwIG9iajw8L1B=</ns2:Base64String>
                <ns2:DocumentType>Pdf</ns2:DocumentType>
            </ns2:Document>
        </ns2:Documents>
```